# swift tableView in custom view programatically - losing reference to controllers delegate and data source

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, weak

I am trying to learn MVVM pattern and writing all my views programatically using Snapkit. I am creating hamburger menu which consist of simple tableView and I have a problem, that my tableView in cusom view is losing delegate and data source references on the view controller. I also tried using UITableViewController, but result is the same, here is my code:

**ViewModel:**

```
class SideMenuViewModel {

    let cellId = "SideMenuCellId"
    weak var delegate: SideMenuViewModelDelegate?
    private let cells: [SideMenuItemStruct] = [SideMenuItemStruct(type: .allDogs, title: "ALL DOGOS"),
                                           SideMenuItemStruct(type: .randomDog, title: "RANDOM DOGO")]

    init(delegate: SideMenuViewModelDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }

    var numberOfRows: Int {
        return cells.count
    }

    func selectedMenuItem(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch SideMenuItemsEnum(rawValue: indexPath.row) {
        case .allDogs?:
            delegate?.selectedMenuItem(selectedItem:        SideMenuItemsEnum.allDogs)
        case .randomDog?:
            delegate?.selectedMenuItem(selectedItem: SideMenuItemsEnum.randomDog)
        default:
            print("error when choosing menu item")
        }
    }

    func cellForRow(_ tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? SideMenuCell else {
            fatalError("could not deque Side menu cell")
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.setUpCell(sideMenuItem: cells[indexPath.row])
        return cell
        }
}
```

**View:**

```
class SideMenuView: UIView {

    var sideMenuTableView = UITableView()

    let sideMenuButton = UIButton(type: .system)

    weak var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
        get {
            return sideMenuTableView.delegate
        }
        set {
            sideMenuTableView.delegate = newValue
        }
    }

    weak var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? {
        get {
            return sideMenuTableView.dataSource
        }
        set {
            sideMenuTableView.dataSource = newValue
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    private func initUI() {
        addSubview(sideMenuButton)
        addSubview(sideMenuTableView)

        setUpSideMenuButton()
        setUpSideMenuTableView()
    }

    private func setUpSideMenuButton() {
        sideMenuButton.setTitle("DELEGATE", for: .normal)
        sideMenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPrint), for: .touchUpInside)
        sideMenuButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonPrint() {
        print("delegate: \(String(describing: sideMenuTableView.delegate)), data source: \(String(describing: sideMenuTableView.dataSource))")
    }

    private func setUpSideMenuTableView() {
        sideMenuTableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(sideMenuButton.snp.bottom)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self)
            make.left.equalTo(self)
            make.right.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

}
```

**And my View Controller:**

```
class SideMenuController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let viewModel: SideMenuViewModel

    fileprivate var sideMenuView: SideMenuView {
        return view as! SideMenuView
    }

    init(viewModel: SideMenuViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let sideMenuView = SideMenuView()
        sideMenuView.sideMenuTableView.delegate = self
        sideMenuView.sideMenuTableView.dataSource = self
        view = sideMenuView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sideMenuView.sideMenuTableView.register(SideMenuCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: viewModel.cellId)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension SideMenuController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel.numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return viewModel.cellForRow(tableView, indexPath: indexPath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        viewModel.selectedMenuItem(indexPath: indexPath)
        print("awd")
    }

}
```

[Simulater after init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHNn6.png)

[Simulator after scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqBou.png)

[DELEGATE button tapped result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECQ1u.png)

I am learning from few tutorials and they didn't had this problem, but they were all using Interface builders, which I want to avoid. Please, let me know, if I am doing something really wrong, thanks.

**SOLUTION**

I found out, I made a really huge mistake outside of this showed code, I initialized SideMenuController in a function and didn't keep reference to it, so naturaly it was automaticly deinitialized after end of a function. It was a really bad mistake. Thanks for all answers, code here is working, but I refactored it according to answer.

Comment: Where do you actually set sideMenuView's delegate and dataSource? I only see that you set sideMenu's tableView's delegate and dataSource directly inside SideMenuController.

Comment: I tried multiple apprpuches, setting it directly to tableview, setting in when I initialize SideMenuView. Here I am doing let sideMenuView = SideMenuView()
        sideMenuView.sideMenuTableView.delegate = self
        sideMenuView.sideMenuTableView.dataSource = self
        view = sideMenuView,
accessing SideMenuView's tableView and setting it directly, when u open screen shots, there is SideMenuView after init and after some scrolling, it's set innitialy, then lost.

Comment: `weak` computed properties make no sense. Can you explain what you mean by "after scroll"?  Your tableview only has two rows, so it should be able to scroll.

Comment: By scroll I mean I drag tableView up or down, it tries to deque cells, but when data source is nil, it;s not dequing anything. In third screen shot is output, when I click on DELEGATE button, it always gives me that output, only time I could see delegate and data source are set, it's when I printed it immediately after setting it. Hope it does make sense, I can provide more code or screens.

Comment: You should start by properly separating the concerns. What is your model? Just an array of menu item names. What is your view model? The same, so you can probably ignore the model part and just create the view model. The view consists of the tableview and the button. The view should implement all of the tableview delegate and data source methods. Your controller instantiates the view, supplies a view model instance and sets itself as the view delegate (`sideMenuViewModelDelegate`). `didSelect` in your view will call the relevant method in the `sideMenuViewModelDelegate`

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Maybe I will try different approach then, because I am not experienced enough to use something like RxSwift and RxCocoa for biding. In one tutorial I saw that viewModel was basicly just mapped struct from model to set up view in cell, and controller was downloading data, link to video: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06RE9A_8Ks] . What do you think of this approuch to MVVM, I am still learning, so I really don't know, where to put which logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have been hacking on this for a while and it looks like code has ended up a bit all over the place.

If you are going to follow MVVM then you need to think about the role of each component.

- Model - An array of `SideMenuItem`
- ViewModel - In this case it is the same as your Model so you can dispense with the Model and just use the ViewModel.  In more complex examples, the ViewModel maps back to the Model, exposing on the data required by the view and performing any required translations
- View - The actual visual elements; In this case just a tableview (although you also have a button for debugging)
- Finally, you still have the View Controller that brings it all together

**ViewModel**

```
struct SideMenuViewModel {
    let items = [SideMenuItemStruct(type: .allDogs, title: "ALL DOGOS"),                                           
                 SideMenuItemStruct(type: .randomDog, title: "RANDOM DOGO")]
}
```

**View**

```
class SideMenuView: UIView { 

    weak var viewModel: SideMenuViewModel?
    weak var delegate: SideMenuViewDelegate? // Was SideMenuViewModelDelegate

    private let sideMenuButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    private var sideMenuTableView = UITableView()
    private let cellId = "YourCellID"

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initUI()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    private func initUI() {
        addSubview(sideMenuButton)
        addSubview(sideMenuTableView)

        setUpSideMenuButton()
        setUpSideMenuTableView()
    }

    private func setUpSideMenuButton() {
        sideMenuButton.setTitle("DELEGATE", for: .normal)
        sideMenuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPrint), for: .touchUpInside)
        sideMenuButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(self)
            make.centerX.equalTo(self)
        }
    }

    @objc func buttonPrint() {
        print("delegate: \(String(describing: sideMenuTableView.delegate)), data source: \(String(describing: sideMenuTableView.dataSource))")
    }

    private func setUpSideMenuTableView() {
        sideMenuTableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(sideMenuButton.snp.bottom)
            make.bottom.equalTo(self)
            make.left.equalTo(self)
            make.right.equalTo(self)
        }
        sideMenuTableView.datasource = self
        sideMenuTableView.delegate = self
        sideMenuTableView.register(SideMenuCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }

}

extension SideMenuView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return viewModel?.numberOfRows ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as? SideMenuCell else {
            fatalError("could not deque Side menu cell")
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.setUpCell(sideMenuItem: self.viewModel!.items[indexPath.row])
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let menuItem = self.viewModel!.items[indexPath.row]
        self.delegate?.didSelect(menuItem)
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class SideMenuController: UIViewController {

    fileprivate let viewModel: SideMenuViewModel

    fileprivate var sideMenuView: SideMenuView {
        return view as! SideMenuView
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let sideMenuView = SideMenuView()
        sideMenuView.delegate = self
        sideMenuView.viewModel = viewModel
        view = sideMenuView
    }

    init(viewModel: SideMenuViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension SideMenuController: SideMenuViewDelegate {


    // TODO: Implement delegate method for menu selection


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just have one last question. Do you think creating subviews in viewController would't be good ? I wanted to achvieve as much async code as I could, but it went well over my head.

Comment: Personally, I use storyboards whenever I can. Even if I was doing this in code, I would have just had the ViewController class.